# "Like button" don't work for application page

Tags: facebook-like

I want to create like button inside application for its profile page.
Button renders, but gives error when clicked:

> The page at
>   http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=151273804972407 could
>   not be reached.

Strange, because this page exists. The same situation is, when I'm using this link in plugin's code generator ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ )
It seems to work with other applications (other application id).

Please advice!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was to create new application. For the new one - with exactly the same settings - "like button" works fine. Strange, isn't it?